# Actions On Google não persiste dados do conv.user.params

Tags: node.js

Ao criar uma Action para Google Assistant, no Backend (Webhook Fulfillment) estou utilizando `conv.user.params` (User Storage) para armazenar os dados de usuário (como está na documentação). Um exemplo simples de uso é a criação do Id de Usuário `conv.user.params.id = uuidv4();`.

Para maioria dos usuários isso funciona normalmente, porém um comportamento inesperado acontece em algumas outras contas, toda vez que o usuário acessa novamente a Action, o `conv.user.params` está completamente vazio, como se ele estivesse acessando a primeira vez.

Isso pode se tornar um problema na hora de criar relatórios de retenção de usuário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que alguns usuário, na sua conta Google, na parte de "Web Activites" vem desabilitado por padrão a opção de "Incluir o histórico do Chrome e a atividade em sites", assim, a Action jamais irá salvar informações pessoais dele na nuvem, logo nada colocado em `conv.user.params` irá persistir.
https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/storage-user#expiration_of_user_storage_data

Isso geralmente acontece em contas compartilhadas ou contas criadas automaticamente para funcionários de
empresa. Só pode ser resolvido solicitando que o usuário verifique habilite essa opção. Visto que a própria Google não informa isso, nem faz questão de deixar isso claro ao usuário, quando alguma informação está sendo gravada.

Na configurações da conta google, clique em Privacidade e Personalização
[image: Na configurações da conta google, clique em Privacidade e Personalização]

Selecione Atividade na Web e de Apps
[image: Selecione Atividade na Web e de Apps]

Habilite Incluir o histórico do Chrome e a atividade em sites, apps e dispositivos que usam serviços do Google
[image: Habilite Incluir o histórico do Chrome e a atividade em sites, apps e dispositivos que usam serviços do Google]

Ao final atualize a página do simulador, e teste novamente.